# Powerpoint 2007 full of linked images that don't display in Impress

Tags: images, libre-office, animated-gif

I recently installed LibreOffice.  I have a large Powerpoint 2007
slide deck that contains a lot of linked images.  None of the show
up as pictures in Impress, be it in full screen slide show view or normal
view.  I see only box outlines with the file name on the upper left
corner.  Also, the motion graphics GIF files that are actually in the
slide deck file do not display motion.

**Does Impress normally handle linked files created by Powerpoint 2007?**

**If not, what is a good way to fix this for a large slide deck?**

**Do GIF figures (that are linked to) display their motion graphics in
slide show view?**

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you have to recreate the links for them to work. Perhaps the answers on this [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473031/automatically-update-linked-images-in-presentation-mode-in-impress) can help you

Comment: Thanks, spike_66, but I'm not really trying to update images in presentation mode.  However, I found the problem.  The presentation and linked files are on a USB stick.  On the original computer, it was one letter drive. On my current computer, it is a different letter drive. Once I changed the letter drive back to original letter, the linked images showed.  However, the aspect ratios and cropping are wrong.  There's no avoiding having to each and every image on each and every slide.  :(